# Why does ng-model in a select return string and not JSON?

Tags: angularjs, json, drop-down-menu, angular-ngmodel

I have the following code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="existing-phases" ng-model="selectedPhase">
    <option disabled selected value>-- select an option --</option>
    <option ng-repeat="p in existingPhases" value="{{p}}">{{ p.Name }</option>
</select>
```

When I select an option in my select I was hoping to get the JSON corresponding to the selected phase which should be like this:

```
{"ID":2,"Name":"Outlook"}
```

However, I'm getting the JSON as a string for some reason:

```
"{\"ID\":2,\"Name\":\"Outlook\"}"
```

How can I make it so that the ng-model returns the JSON and not a string?

P.S.: I don't want to convert it afterwards in a method, because I know that you can do that with JSON.Parse().

Update:

Debug print:

[image]

Comment: *"However, I'm getting the JSON as a string for some reason:"* well... json is a string afterall. If it weren't a string, it wouldn't be json.

Comment: @KevinB I'm sorry, I didn't know how to explain it any better. That's why I added the examples, so there wouldn't be any confusion.

Comment: How/where are you seeing `"{\"ID\":2,\"Name\":\"Outlook\"}"`?

Comment: When I debug, that is what is inside $scope.selectedPhase, instead of the normal JSON.

Comment: using breakpoints? or did you log it using some code. **Show us**.

Comment: Using breakpoints.

Comment: @KevinB I added it to the question.

Comment: I understand is not a javascript object but a string formatted as json but not a json object so you wont have access to its attributes, as im having the same issue had to convert it using json.parse, as you can see when is a red text in the debug console is a string not a json object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I was mistaken but I was not. If you use ng-repeat instead of ng-options your ng-model's property gets set as a JSON string rather than an actual javascript object. I found this question that explains it better: [Angular UI Select2, why does ng-model get set as JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535560/angular-ui-select2-why-does-ng-model-get-set-as-json-string).

So in order to fix my problem I had to change from ng-repeat to ng-options.

Answer (score 1):

I setup a plunker with you code and seems to work normally

https://plnkr.co/edit/Q8Cmknqg8bGBc5hABtF1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.existingPhases = [
          {"ID":1,"Name":"a"},
          {"ID":2,"Name":"b"},
          {"ID":3,"Name":"c"},
          {"ID":4,"Name":"d"},
          {"ID":5,"Name":"e"}];
        $scope.selectedPhase;
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="FooCtrl">
      <select id="existing-phases" ng-model="selectedPhase">
        <option disabled selected value>-- select an option --</option>
        <option ng-repeat="p in existingPhases" value="{{p}}">{{ p.Name }}</option>
      </select>
      {{selectedPhase}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

please check your code I don't think it's an select directive problem

Comment: I found what was confusing me thanks to your plunker. I was printing the content of the phase like this <pre>{{ phase | json}}</pre> and that pipe was adding the extra backslashes and quotes and because of that I thought I was getting weird values.

Comment: I've made a new answer because I finally found out what was going on.

Comment: I don't understand, based on the code on your question I've shown you that there were no problem at all

Comment: The problem was that the content of the ng-model is a string like this: "{\"ID\":2,\"Name\":\"Outlook\"}" and not an object. That's because when you use ng-repeat instead of ng-options angular does this automatically. If you use ng-options however, the value of the ng-model is an object. I can access its properties and manipulate it how I want it, it's not just a string. With ng-repeat I can't do this:  var a = selectedPhase.Name; but with ng-options I can. The only way to do it with ng-repeat is to do it like this: var a = JSON.Parse(selectedPhase.Name);